# удаление строки из структуры

Tags: c++

После ввода пользователем определенной профессии, вся строка связанная с ею должна удалятся.
Код:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
typedef void MenuFunc();
using namespace std;
void showAll();
void addRecord();
void dellRecord();
void sortByName();
void sortByResult();
void showIt();
int num = 8; int capacity = 9;
struct hospital {
    char emloyes[255];
    char department[255];
    char highness[100];
    int amount;
    hospital* next;
    hospital *head;
    hospital*curr = head;
    hospital*trail = 0;
}Hdoc, zamdoc, doc, nur, san, econ, acc, cadr;
hospital ar[8] = {
    {"chief physician", "all dep", "main", 1},
    {"vice-chief phys", "all dep", "main", 1},
    {"doctors", "all doc-type dep", "medium", 12},
    {"nurses", "all doc-type dep", "medium", 25},
    {"sanitares", "all doc-type dep, maintenance", "low", 40},
    {"economs", "economical dep", "medium", 5},
    {"accountants", "economy dep", "main/medium", 5},
    {"other", "HR dep, maintenance, etc", "medium/low", 10}
};
int getInt(string prompt, int min, int max) {
    int num = 0; string s;
    do {
        cout << prompt;
        getline(cin, s);
        num = atoi(s.c_str());

    } while (num < min || num > max);
    num = atoi(s.c_str());
    return num;
}
char* getStr(string prompt, int maxMemory) {
    cout << prompt;
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    if (s.length() >= maxMemory)
        s = s.substr(0, maxMemory - 1);
    //allocate memory for char array
    char* cStr = new char[s.length() + 1];
    return strcpy(cStr, s.c_str());
}
struct MenuUnit {
    string text;
    MenuFunc* func;
};
MenuUnit menu[] = {
    {"Hospital structure", showAll},
    {"Add record", addRecord},
    {"Delete record", dellRecord},
    {"Sort by profession", sortByName},
    {"Sort by amount", sortByResult},
    {"Find the department with less amount of employes", showIt},
    {"Exit", NULL}
};
int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitleA("Hospital");
    while (true) {
        int count = 0;
        for (; ; count++) {
            cout << " " << count + 1 << ". "
                << menu[count].text << endl;
            if (menu[count].text.compare("Exit") == 0)
                break;
        }
        int variant = getInt(" Enter variant number, please ", 1, count + 1);
        if (variant == count + 1) {
            cout << "\n End.\n";
            break;
        }
        menu[variant - 1].func();
    }
    system("pause");
}
void showAll() {
    cout << "Call fucntion showAll()" << endl;
    cout << "Here:\n";
    printf(" %-*s %-*s %-*s %s\n", 20, "Employes: ", 25, "Department:", 30, "Higness: ", "Amount: ");
    int i = 0; char j = 0;
    for (; i < num, j < num; i++, j++) {
        printf("%-*s %-*s %-*s %d \n", 20, ar[j].emloyes, 25, ar[j].department, 30, ar[j].highness, ar[i].amount);
    }
}
void growAr() {
    capacity = capacity + 10;
    hospital* newAr = new hospital[capacity];
    // Copy old array to new
    memcpy(newAr, ar, num * sizeof(hospital));
    hospital* oldAr = ar;
    swap(newAr, oldAr);
    // Old Deleting
    delete[] oldAr;

}
void addRecord() {
    if (num == capacity)  growAr();
    strcpy(ar[num].emloyes, getStr("Enter profession: ", 255));
    strcpy(ar[num].department, getStr("Enter department ", 255));
    strcpy(ar[num].highness, getStr("Enter higness ", 255));
    ar[num].amount = getInt("Enter amount ", 0, 50);
    num++;
    showAll();
}
void delRecord() {
    strcpy(ar[num].emloyes, getStr("Enter profession: ", 255));
    int i = 0; char j = 0;
    for (; i < num, j < num; i++, j++) {
        ar[j].emloyes = "";//127
        ar[j].department = "";//128
        ar[j].highness = "";//129
        ar[i].amount = "";//130
    }
}
typedef bool Comparator(hospital, hospital);
void sort(Comparator* test) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num; j++)
            if ((!test(ar[i], ar[j]))) {
                hospital x = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[j];
                ar[j] = x;
            }
}
bool testByName(hospital Hdoc, hospital zamdoc)
{
    return strcmp(Hdoc.emloyes, zamdoc.emloyes) <= 0;
}
void sortByName() {
    sort(testByName);
    showAll();
}
bool testByResult(hospital Hdoc, hospital doc) {
    if (Hdoc.highness != doc.highness)
        return Hdoc.highness < doc.highness;
    if (Hdoc.amount != doc.amount)
        return Hdoc.amount < doc.amount;
    return strcmp(Hdoc.emloyes, doc.emloyes) <= 0;
}
void sortByResult() {
    sort(testByResult);
    showAll();
}
void showIt() {
    int ball;
    cout << " Enter the number of peoples in department";
    cin >> ball;
    sort(testByResult);
    cout << "\nDepartments with less amount: " << ball << ":\n";
    printf(" %-*s %-*s %s %s\n", 30, "Employe", 50, "Department ", 100, "Higness", "Amount");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (ar[i].amount >= ball)
            printf(" %-*s %-*s %s %3d\n", 30, ar[i].emloyes, 50, ar[i].department, ar[i].highness, ar[i].amount);

    }
}
```

компилятор жалуется "выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением" в 127-129 строке и на "значение типа "const char *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "int" в 130.
буду крайне признательна за помощь с кодом!

Comment: @хайл, а до 127 строчки че вручную считать что ли ? Вы пометить комментарием хотя бы 127-129 строчку ни как не смогли ?

Comment: @Optimus1, исправила

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  struct hospital 
> {
> char emloyes[255];
> char department[255];
> char highness[100];
> int amount;
>  }
> ```

```
ar[j].emloyes = "";//127
ar[j].department = "";//128
ar[j].highness = "";//129
ar[i].amount = "";//130
```

-Собствено, если Вам нужно обнулит массив используйт`е memset().

```
memset(ar[j].emloyes, 0, 254);
```

Или за место массива char используйт`е std::string и не парьтесь.

```
std::string emloyes;
emloyes = "";
```

-Вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной int - некое пустое строковое текстовое значение ??
Переменной в которой хранятся числовые значения - вы хотите присвоить строку?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! ;;

Comment: https://ideone.com/V05Nkm ???